# Can a child window know when parent window is moved?

Tags: c#, user-interface, mfc

I have developed a dll which is loaded from a thirdparty application.
The application does not provide me any events like WM_SIZE, WM_MOVE etc.
My dll displays a window (dialog) which is child of the main application.
I want that my window should move whenever main application is resized or moved.
How can I achieve this? As I said, the main application does not provide any WM_SIZE or WM_MOVE events.
Is there a way to subscribe to events of the application using the application handle?
OR can a child window know when main application is moved or resized without these events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a window has a style WS_CHILD it never receives a WM_MOVE or WM_SIZE message when the parent moves!

Why should it? Its position (relative to the parent) and its size doesn't change. Also the OS Windows takes care about any repainting that has to occur by uncovering sections of the window.

So when you are saying that the window should move with the parent and it doesn't than the window isn't a child of the parent. (Style WS_CHILD). Recheck this with Spy++. Or maybe you have only an owned window. (Your question isn't detailed enough).

If you have a non WS_CHILD window and you want it to move with another window, you can use a timer to recheck if the other window moved. Or if the window is in the same process you can subclass the window and post your own message to your window when the parent receives WM_SIZE/WM_MOVE.

Comment: as per your suggestion, I checked the window with spy++. 
You are correct that it is not a child window but an owned window. 
After changing it to child window, it doesn't need to know if the application is resized or moved. It is taken care by itself. 
Thank you for your help.